# Make easier to read numbers in Lua

Tags: string, lua

So for the past hour or so I've been having issues with this function to make numbers easier to read.
In its current state the function does work for numbers with a length below 6 characters like so.

```
1000,000
100,000
```

Please forgive my amateur ways with variables.

```
function neatnumber(number)
    local nslen = string.len(tostring(number))
    if nslen <= 3 then
        return number
    end
    local ns = tostring(number)
    local nslen = math.floor(string.len(ns) / 3)-1
    for i=1,nslen do
        neat = string.sub(ns,-#ns,#s-(3*i)) .. "," .. string.sub(ns,#ns-(2))
    end
    return neat
end
```

Comment: I would very strongly recommend you make all of those variables in your function (like `numberstringlen` and `numberstring`) `local`.  Global variables should be used sparingly, and certainly not for something like this.

Comment: You're right, as I said amateur at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way, but you can use `string.gsub` in a loop.

```lua
local function neatnumber(n)
    local s, i = string.format('%0.f', n)
    repeat
        s, i = s:gsub('^(%-?%d+)(%d%d%d)', '%1,%2')
    until i == 0
    return s
end
```

The gsub pattern scans the string for a number (which might be negative) looking for consecutive decimal digits, and capturing the whole sequence up to the last three digits. A second capture gets the last three digits. The substitution concatenates the two captures and adds a comma between.

This should work for any size integer (positive or negative):

```
neatnumber(2^53)   -->  9,007,199,254,740,992
neatnumber(-2^53)  --> -9,007,199,254,740,992
```

Comment: Doesn't it matter if I use a loop instead of what @greatwolf answered?

Comment: @Ferdi It shouldn't matter. I think greatwolf was just showing that there are multiple ways to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar solution also using `string.gsub` but without loops:

```
function neatnumber(n, delim)
    delim = delim or ','
    n = ('%0.f'):format(n)

    local groups = math.ceil(#n / 3) - 1
    n = n:reverse()
    n = n:gsub('(%d%d%d)', '%1' .. delim, groups)
    return n:reverse()
end
```